# Rails form select helper populated in edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In an existing codebase, one attribute of the `discount` model is `discount_type`.  Since there are only 2 types of discounts (percentage and cash) used in this system, they are hardcoded as `percentage` or `cash` throughout the system, there is no `discount_types` table or anything to map to.

In the form, there is the following code:

```
=form_for @discount do |f|
  ...
  =f.select :discount_type, options_for_select(["percentage", "cash"])
  ...
```

This works great for new discounts, but when pulling up the form to edit a discount, `percentage` is always selected, no matter what the `discount` object's `discount_type` is.  How do we get the form to default to the `discount_type` of the object being edited?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't simple

```
= f.select :discount_type, ["percentage", "cash"]
```

be enough?

Comment: Yep, dunno why I didn't find that anywhere...  too easy.